# Is there a possibility of accessing a (web-)server on a github-action

Tags: github-actions

I like to get access to a webserver which is started on github-actions. I tried it via enabling ssh for debugging (https://github.com/lhotari/action-upterm) and then using ssh port forwarding as described here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling/
If it would work as I expect I could get access via browser at http://localhost:<forwarded port> from my local machine to the remote one on github-actions.
But I can't get it to work. I can see that there is a ssh-client connected on github-actions and on my machine something is listening on the forwarded port. But access via browser or curl isn't possible.
Maybe there is a much better approach to achieve this goal or am I missing something?

Comment: I've used https://github.com/mxschmitt/action-tmate in the past.